# 'store result score @s' storing a 0 to the scoreboard no matter what

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a an area with lots of armour stands. Under each one is a dispenser with 1 - 54 items in the first slot, which is its sort of 'id'.
I need to temporarily save the number of items in each of those dispensers to a scoreboard which I am doing like so:

```
execute as @e[tag=char] at @e[tag=char] store result score @s temp run data get block ~ ~-1 ~ Items[0].Count
```

however, no matter the number of items inside or anything, it will always store a 0.
[image]
I run one similar command before which is:

```
execute as @e[tag=getblock] at @e[tag=getblock] unless block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:air store result score blockCount load run data get block ~ ~-1 ~ Items[0].Count
```

and this runs perfectly. There is only one amour stand with that tag but that shouldn't matter because I am running the other command using `@s` which will just use the UUID of the entity.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is more than one armour stand, your `at` argument should be `@s` instead of `@e[tag=char]`.

It's a complicated explanation why.

Place down two armour stands in your test world, name them `One` and `Two` respectively, and tag them `test`. Let's run a few commands on them (paste them into your chat):

```
/execute as @e[tag=test] run say Hello, World!
```

Result:

```
[Armour Stand] Hello, World!
[Armour Stand] Hello, World!
```

Now let's try using `at` instead of `as`:

```
/execute at @e[tag=test] run say Hello, World!
```

Result:

```
[ExpertCoder14] Hello, World!
[ExpertCoder14] Hello, World!
```

It looks like the command is executed twice, by your player, once at each position.à

Now let's combine them. Try the following:

```
/execute as @e[tag=test] at @e[tag=test] run say Hello, World!
```

... and you get 4 messages, 2 from each armour stand.

What is happening with your old command is that each armour stand is executing the `/data get` with *each* armour stand, not with itself. So armour stand 1 will execute `/data get` with *all the other armour stands*, not just itself.

Fixed command:

```
execute as @e[tag=char] at @s store result score @s temp run data get block ~ ~-1 ~ Items[0].Count
```

Comment: Right - that makes total sense! I assumed it would work because the other commands worked, but they only have 1 amour stand with that tag. I guess, unless you wanted that behaviour, it's a good idea to use `at @s` to avoid this.